# How does one organise and share artefacts used solely for DevOps and Automation purposes?

Tags: version-control, automation, devops

I have recently stepped into the world of DevOps, CI/CD and Automation and I am confused about how artefacts used solely for these purposes are shared and tracked using Version Control, and I haven't really found many resources that cover this topic online.

Some artefacts, such as `Dockerfiles`, `Jenkinsfiles`, and `.travis.yml`, are generally included with the project source code and thus are naturally organised and tracked using Version Control.

However, what if I have a bunch of automation scripts? How can I share/track/bundle my Nginx configuration for a project, or an Ansible Playbook that I use to deploy build artefacts to a bunch of nodes, etc with the rest of my team, or to a future DevOps engineer who might take my place?

Answer (score 0):

> However, what if I have a bunch of automation scripts? How can I share/track/bundle my Nginx configuration for a project, or an Ansible Playbook that I use to deploy build artefacts to a bunch of nodes, etc with the rest of my team, or to a future DevOps engineer who might take my place?

Convert your configurations/automation scripts into [Sparrow](http://sparrowhub.org/) packages then distribute them across teams. There is the nice [introduction](https://dev.to/melezhik/distributing-portable-scripts-with-sparrow-8f4) on that on dev.to . You can use private Sparrow repositories if you concern privacy.